# Plugin or extension for IDE, which can help to find where were methods declared

Tags: javascript, plugins

For example:
There is a class.
In this class we have a method calling: "this.methodName()".
This method was declared in another place.
This class extends from another class. Another class (which is a superclass for this class) extends from another class and it can go on for a really very long time.
If I try to use the command "go to definition", it shows many possible places for this method declaration.
Is there a plugin or an extension or maybe another way to go direct to the place where this method was declared?

Thank You for Your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for your editor and there are many useful extensions for your development
[image]